# How to setup multiple lambda RequestHandlers in quarkus

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus, aws-sam

I am trying to deploy multiple functions from a single Quarkus project. I am using a SAM template similar to this [one](https://github.com/Vadym79/AWSLambdaJavaSnapStart/blob/38b86962a8a0dec89a926313153bff17a2067149/quarkus/template.yaml).

SAM deploy works fine, and I am able to deploy both to AWS and locally with sam local start-api.

The trouble I am having is with the mvn compile quarkus:dev command. I want to run integration tests without SAM. When I run mvn compile quarkus:dev, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple handler classes, either specify the quarkus.lambda.handler property, or make sure there is only a single com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler or, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler implementation in the deployment
```

Is there a way I can use multiple handlers in quarkus:dev, or is it simply not supported?

My SAM template already has the environment property QUARKUS_LAMBDA_HANDLER.